series about a boy who has a chip in his brain- he is taken in and hooked up to machines, to be used for years and he loses his memory
I don’t know much about the book, a friend told me about it a couple months ago. But what I remember is that people had chips in their brains and this one character has certain abilities. There’s some sort of war? And it’s digital. He’s captured and hooked up to machines and forced to ‘help’ and he does this for years, essentially being sustained by machines. This happens over a series.
My friend read it around three years ago I’d say, so it would likely be in the range of young adult or slightly lower.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How many books in the series?  How long ago did your friend read them?

@DavidW just a couple, maybe three? she had read them years ago and just re-listened to them this year

Sounds like Johnny Mnemonic salute like the ones toward Better off dead from Gross Pointe Blank.

What is "years ago"? To someone who is 12, that might be 3 years. to someone who is 80, that could be 60 years.

@FreeMan I can’t say the exact time frame, but if I had to guess, three years ago? not very long honestly

Edit that into the question so others know.
